# Is it possible to move an element upon keydown using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

How can I move an element horizontally by 10pixels  upon an arrow keydown event in JQuery? For instance I have

```
  <p class="move">This is to be moved</p>
```

I have tried the following code but it does not work..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>JQuery(2)</title>
<style type="text/css">
.Test1{width:100px;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="jquery.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {


$('#target').keydown(function() {
  alert('Handler for .keydown() called.');
});

});
</script>

</head>

<body>


<div id="parent">
<p id="target">This is a text</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above was supposed to alert me upon a keydown event but it does not..How can I fix this?In other words it does not capture my keydown event..

Comment: Move how? Absolute positioning is CSS? DOM Manipulation? What have you tried?

Comment: Are you wanting to created a drag'n'drop effect? Please add more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general? You could handle the keyDown event on its parent.

For example:

http://jsfiddle.net/NXEU4/1/

Difficult to provide a more detailed answer without more information.

**EDIT**

Your code does not work because your browser does not allow the `<p>` to receive input focus, and hence will not have the keyDown event fire.

The example I provided is shifting an absolutely positioned element. For your example, you could simply increase the `margin-left` style.

**EDIT2**

Oops, might want to update the link as well.

Comment: @Vimal it is most likely browser dependent (i.e. whether they consider `body` to be capable of input focus. I have updated it to be a bit more general.

Comment: With firefox 5, it works by changing `$("body")` to `$(document)`

Comment: @Johnny5 Yup, that's the exact change I made, and have tested it on IE8 and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You actually want #target to be an input. You can't technically 'keydown' on a standard html tag element, it needs to be something that can have an active 'focus' state, in order for it to listen to the keyboard inputs. Your

tag will not know when there is a keydown action because you can't apply one to it.

```
<form>
  <input id="target" type="text" value="Hello there" />
</form>
<p id="moving_p">i can move when you key down in the input box above</p>
```

and your script:

```
$(function() {
  $('#target').keydown(function() {
    $('#moving_p').animate({marginLeft:10+'px'});
  });
});
```